# Read specific data from text file

Tags: c#, .net, file

I have a text file as follows(it is having more than hundered thousands of lines):

```
Header
AGROUP1
ADATA1|0000
ADATA2|0001
ADATA3|0002
D0000|TNE
D0001|TNE
D0002|TNE
AGROUP2
ADATA1|0000
ADATA2|0001
ADATA3|0002
D0000|TNE
D0001|TNE
D0002|TNE
AGROUP3
ADATA1|0000
ADATA2|0001
ADATA3|0002
D0000|TNE
D0001|TNE
D0002|TNE
```

Infact it has more than hundered thousands lines of code.

I need to read data based on group
For example in a method:

```
public void ReadData(string strGroup)
{
    if(strGroup == "AGROUP2)
       //Read from the text file starting from line  "AGROUP2" to "AGROUP3"(i.e lines under AGROUP2)
}
```

What i have tried is

```
 public void ReadData(string strGroup)
    {
             bool start = false;
             while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {
                        if (line == strGroup && line.Length == 5)
                            start = true;
                        else if (line.Length == 5)
                            start = false;
                        if(start)
                            yield return line;
                    }
    }
```

It is working fine, Performance wise, it takes longer since my text file is a very very huge file....There is if condition on every line in the method.

IS the a better way to do this?

Comment: Why have you tagged your question "java" when it's presumably C#? Also, please be aware that "lakh" is not a well-known measure, internationally.

Comment: I have not tagged "java", I have no clue how that was tagged. I assume that might be tagged by the moderators(not sure). I will change the lakh word.

Comment: Is there anything you know about the structure of the file that might help (sorted, containing jumps)? If not, you're destined to search from top to bottom and you will only be able to increase the speed by manipulating the buffers (reading a single line at the time can be slow) or do some pre-processing (splitting/sorting the file)

Comment: 1) just read the file and add all data to a datatable (you can use | (pipe) symbol as a separator ) 2) make all your decision process on that datatable. Reading a file (i mean an i/o process) is very expensive. You should handle this in a shortest time. You can loop over the datatable and can do other thinks.

Comment: @AdamRight - this might be feasible but I'd be careful to read a huge file into memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is anything you know about the structure of the file that might help you could use that:

- if the list is sorted you might know when to stop parsing.
- if the list contains jump tables or an index you could skip lines
- if the groups have a specific number of lines you can skip those

If not, you're destined to search from top to bottom and you will only be able to increase the speed using technical tricks:

- read batches of lines instead of single lines
- try to prevent creating many tiny objects (strings) in your code that might choke the garbage collector
- if you need to do a lot of random access (going back and forth throughout the file) you might consider indexing or splitting the file first.

Answer (score 0):

What if you use bash command to cut the huge file into smaller ones with AGROUP# as the first line. I think bash commands are more optimized.

Comment: any example of bash commands. i am not aware of bash commands..Please.